# Cluster/cox models and models including the lag of residuals return no confidence interval for coefficients

Tags: r, spatstat

I am trying to explain the localisation of a series of points (urban commons) in Amsterdam using a series of indicators linked to urban form and land uses and prices. However, almost any model I try except a simple poisson model (using `ppm()`) returns no confidence intervals or contrast statistics. I suspect it has to do with multicolinearity because models with less variables form do return them. The same if I try to add the spatial lags of the residuals (they autocorrelate). However, I do not know how to solve this issue. The data I am using can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15qGG8qqkE4ip7pwP5iaEoDIFBYrAnQ74/view?usp=sharing).

The code I am using is the following.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(terra)
library(stars)
library(spatstat)
library(sfdep)
library(stargazer)
library(tmap)

# Model 1: poisson
ppm(unmark(points) ~ diversity + total_commercial + pct_built_area + airbnb + 
      buildings_1000sqm + avg_height + avg_volume + 
      avg_value_22 + ratio_0222 + green_pct, data = grid_1000)
```

This returns the following, which is pretty much as expected.

```
Nonstationary Poisson process
Fitted to point pattern dataset ‘unmark(points)’

Log intensity:  ~diversity + total_commercial + pct_built_area + airbnb + buildings_1000sqm + avg_height + avg_volume + avg_value_22 + ratio_0222 + green_pct

Fitted trend coefficients:
      (Intercept)         diversity  total_commercial    pct_built_area            airbnb buildings_1000sqm        avg_height        avg_volume      avg_value_22 
    -1.425462e+01      6.072734e-01     -1.846563e+00      3.103554e+00      7.210381e+00     -9.203244e-01      2.243507e-02     -2.284920e-05     -1.906361e-04 
       ratio_0222         green_pct 
     3.561508e-01     -1.142325e+00 

                       Estimate         S.E.       CI95.lo       CI95.hi Ztest        Zval
(Intercept)       -1.425462e+01 9.964266e-01 -1.620758e+01 -1.230166e+01   *** -14.3057356
diversity          6.072734e-01 6.179132e-01 -6.038141e-01  1.818361e+00         0.9827811
total_commercial  -1.846563e+00 2.969206e+00 -7.666100e+00  3.972974e+00        -0.6219045
pct_built_area     3.103554e+00 2.835231e+00 -2.453397e+00  8.660504e+00         1.0946387
airbnb             7.210381e+00 2.675235e+00  1.967017e+00  1.245375e+01    **   2.6952327
buildings_1000sqm -9.203244e-01 3.885961e-01 -1.681959e+00 -1.586900e-01     *  -2.3683314
avg_height         2.243507e-02 4.465918e-02 -6.509531e-02  1.099655e-01         0.5023620
avg_volume        -2.284920e-05 2.069819e-05 -6.341691e-05  1.771852e-05        -1.1039223
avg_value_22      -1.906361e-04 1.276126e-04 -4.407521e-04  5.947991e-05        -1.4938664
ratio_0222         3.561508e-01 3.409597e-01 -3.121179e-01  1.024420e+00         1.0445540
green_pct         -1.142325e+00 6.795564e-01 -2.474231e+00  1.895810e-01        -1.6809864
Problem:
 Values of the covariates ‘diversity’, ‘total_commercial’, ‘pct_built_area’, ‘airbnb’, ‘buildings_1000sqm’, ‘avg_height’, ‘avg_volume’, 
‘avg_value_22’, ‘ratio_0222’, ‘green_pct’ were NA or undefined at 21% (130 out of 609) of the quadrature points
```

However, K function and other statistics pointed at clustering, so I tried the following formula.

```
kppm(unmark(points) ~ diversity + total_commercial + pct_built_area + airbnb + 
       buildings_1000sqm + avg_height + avg_volume + 
       avg_value_22 + ratio_0222 + green_pct, data = grid_1000, clusters = "Thomas")
```

This returns the following

```
Inhomogeneous cluster point process model
Fitted to point pattern dataset ‘unmark(points)’
Fitted by minimum contrast
    Summary statistic: inhomogeneous K-function

Log intensity:  ~diversity + total_commercial + pct_built_area + airbnb + buildings_1000sqm + avg_height + avg_volume + avg_value_22 + ratio_0222 + green_pct

Fitted trend coefficients:
      (Intercept)         diversity  total_commercial    pct_built_area            airbnb buildings_1000sqm        avg_height        avg_volume      avg_value_22 
    -1.425462e+01      6.072734e-01     -1.846563e+00      3.103554e+00      7.210381e+00     -9.203244e-01      2.243507e-02     -2.284920e-05     -1.906361e-04 
       ratio_0222         green_pct 
     3.561508e-01     -1.142325e+00 

Cluster model: Thomas process
Fitted cluster parameters:
       kappa        scale 
1.457434e-06 7.091338e+00 
Mean cluster size:  [pixel image]

Cluster strength: phi =  1086
Sibling probability: psib =  0.9991
Warning messages:
1: Values of the covariates ‘diversity’, ‘total_commercial’, ‘pct_built_area’, ‘airbnb’, ‘buildings_1000sqm’, ‘avg_height’, ‘avg_volume’, ‘avg_value_22’, ‘ratio_0222’, ‘green_pct’ were NA or undefined at 21% (130 out of 609) of the quadrature points. Occurred while executing: ppm.ppp(Q = X, trend = trend, covariates = covariates, forcefit = TRUE,  
2: Values for 5 query points lying outside the pixel image domain were estimated by projection to the nearest pixel
```

And no confidence intervals.

Another possible model was to include the spatial lag of the residuals of the first model (`mod_total1000`). They were computed as follows

```
sf_res1000_total <- mod1000_total |> 
  residuals() |> 
  Smooth() |> 
  st_as_stars() |> 
  st_set_crs(st_crs(sf_1000)) |> 
  aggregate(sf_1000, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE) |> 
  st_as_sf()

sf_1000$residuals_total <- sf_res1000_total$v


sf_1000 <- sf_1000 |> 
  mutate(nbs = st_contiguity(geom),
         ws = st_weights(nbs)
         lag_restotal = map_dbl(nbs, \(x) mean(residuals_total[x], na.rm = TRUE)))

grid_1000_lag <- sf_1000 |> 
  st_rasterize() |> 
  as.im()
```

The model is computed like so and returns the following result

```
mod1000_totallag <- ppm(unmark(points) ~ diversity + total_commercial + pct_built_area + airbnb + 
                      buildings_1000sqm + avg_height + avg_volume +
                      avg_value_22 + ratio_0222 + green_pct + lag_restotal, data = grid_1000_lag)
```

```
Error in solve.default(M) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.23184e-23
Error in solve.default(M) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.23184e-23
In addition: Warning message:
Cannot compute variance: Fisher information matrix is singular 
Nonstationary Poisson process
Fitted to point pattern dataset ‘unmark(points)’

Log intensity:  ~diversity + total_commercial + pct_built_area + airbnb + buildings_1000sqm + avg_height + avg_volume + avg_value_22 + ratio_0222 + green_pct + 
lag_restotal

Fitted trend coefficients:
      (Intercept)         diversity  total_commercial    pct_built_area            airbnb buildings_1000sqm        avg_height        avg_volume      avg_value_22 
    -1.359816e+01      7.091453e-01     -2.078549e+00      3.121788e+00      8.741966e+00     -9.433598e-01      1.485747e-02     -1.431878e-05     -3.105369e-01 
       ratio_0222         green_pct      lag_restotal 
     3.408182e-01     -1.714836e+00      6.650295e+06 

Standard errors unavailable; variance-covariance matrix is singular
Problem:
 Values of the covariates ‘diversity’, ‘total_commercial’, ‘pct_built_area’, ‘airbnb’, ‘buildings_1000sqm’, ‘avg_height’, ‘avg_volume’, 
‘avg_value_22’, ‘ratio_0222’, ‘green_pct’, ‘lag_restotal’ were NA or undefined at 21% (130 out of 609) of the quadrature points

Warning message:
Cannot compute variance: Fisher information matrix is singular
```

Here is where I'm lost. If I try

```
ppm(unmark(points) ~ lag_restotal, data = grid_1000_lag)
```

I get

```
Nonstationary Poisson process
Fitted to point pattern dataset ‘unmark(points)’

Log intensity:  ~lag_restotal

Fitted trend coefficients:
  (Intercept)  lag_restotal 
    -14.90568 4787774.46856 

                  Estimate         S.E.       CI95.lo       CI95.hi Ztest      Zval
(Intercept)      -14.90568 1.421692e-01     -15.18432     -14.62703   *** -104.8446
lag_restotal 4787774.46856 1.372563e+06 2097600.54921 7477948.38791   ***    3.4882
Problem:
 Values of the covariate ‘lag_restotal’ were NA or undefined at 0.16% (1 out of 609) of the quadrature points
```